# Local Wordpress installs don't verfiy against wp-cli checksum check and how to fix that issue.

Tags: localization, wp-cli, installation

i've installed wp-cli today, while testing i ran into one surprising issue. on `wp core verify-checksums' the following errors showed up:

```
Warning: File doesn't verify against checksum: wp-includes/css/media-views.css
Warning: File doesn't verify against checksum: wp-includes/css/media-views.min.css
Warning: File doesn't verify against checksum: wp-includes/css/media-views-rtl.min.css
Warning: File doesn't verify against checksum: wp-includes/css/media-views-rtl.css
Warning: File doesn't verify against checksum: wp-includes/link-template.php
Warning: File doesn't verify against checksum: wp-includes/taxonomy.php
Warning: File doesn't verify against checksum: wp-admin/css/wp-admin-rtl.min.css
Warning: File doesn't verify against checksum: wp-admin/css/themes.css
Warning: File doesn't verify against checksum: wp-admin/css/wp-admin.min.css
Warning: File doesn't verify against checksum: wp-admin/css/themes-rtl.css
Warning: File doesn't verify against checksum: wp-admin/includes/update-core.php
Warning: File doesn't verify against checksum: wp-admin/user-edit.php
Error: WordPress install doesn't verify against checksums.
```

those files differ for each of my local installs of wordpress i've checked. each was installed as the basic english installation and switched to the german localization a few days or weeks later. I wonder now how to fix those differing md5 checksums. Basically i could download the 4.1 archive and just replace the wp-admin and wp-includes folders ( to save the time in contrast to single handedly exchanging only the differing files). But i wonder do i have to use the english archive or the german? Cuz i've downloaded both and did a diff and they differ:

```
Only in /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressde: liesmich.html
Files /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressen/wp-admin/css/themes-rtl.css and /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressde/wp-admin/css/themes-rtl.css differ
Files /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressen/wp-admin/css/themes.css and /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressde/wp-admin/css/themes.css differ
Files /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressen/wp-admin/css/wp-admin-rtl.min.css and /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressde/wp-admin/css/wp-admin-rtl.min.css differ
Files /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressen/wp-admin/css/wp-admin.min.css and /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressde/wp-admin/css/wp-admin.min.css differ
Files /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressen/wp-admin/includes/update-core.php and /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressde/wp-admin/includes/update-core.php differ
Files /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressen/wp-admin/user-edit.php and /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressde/wp-admin/user-edit.php differ
Files /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressen/wp-config-sample.php and /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressde/wp-config-sample.php differ
Only in /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressde/wp-content: languages
Files /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressen/wp-includes/css/media-views-rtl.css and /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressde/wp-includes/css/media-views-rtl.css differ
Files /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressen/wp-includes/css/media-views-rtl.min.css and /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressde/wp-includes/css/media-views-rtl.min.css differ
Files /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressen/wp-includes/css/media-views.css and /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressde/wp-includes/css/media-views.css differ
Files /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressen/wp-includes/css/media-views.min.css and /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressde/wp-includes/css/media-views.min.css differ
Files /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressen/wp-includes/link-template.php and /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressde/wp-includes/link-template.php differ
Files /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressen/wp-includes/taxonomy.php and /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressde/wp-includes/taxonomy.php differ
Files /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressen/wp-includes/version.php and /Users/myuser/Downloads/wordpressde/wp-includes/version.php differ
```

and do i have to deactivate my plugins before i replace the folders like suggested in http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress or would activate the maintance mode be already enough?

Answer (score 1):

My similar issue was solved with

```
wp core download --force --locale=de_DE
wp core verify-checksums
```

Comment: I would add a note or edit your answer to indicate that the --locale string is specific to YOUR issue, but may not be applicable to most (many?) of the folks that came to this answer via search